# "Python: AttributeError - 'module' object has no attribute 'function_name'"

Tags: python

I'm encountering an `AttributeError` in Python when trying to access a function within a module. I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
python

import my_module

result = my_module.function_name()
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function_name'

I have already checked the module contents using `dir(my_module)` to verify the presence of the function, and it's listed. I'm unsure why this error is occurring. Could someone guide me on resolving this issue?

Comment: importing that way would pull the function into locals. So `function_name()` not `my_module.function_name()`